# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Hiding/Show row depending on Radiobutton

Tags: asp.net, ajax

This is the RadioButton

```
<tr class="choose">
    <td>
        Are you a director or company secretary of this nonprofit?
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="isDirector" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"
                    AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="isDirectorCompleted" Display="None" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Are you company director/secretary must be selected." ControlToValidate="isDirector"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then this is the row im trying to hide

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="test">
            <td class="title">
                Director First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DirectorfirstNametxt" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="None" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Director First Name is required." ControlToValidate="DirectorfirstNametxt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I basically want to hide/show the entire TR but basically it does nothing, and depending if use `updatemode="conditional"` it seems to work but adds an additional tr on top of screen.

```
protected void isDirector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isDirector.SelectedValue == "True")
    {
        test.Visible = false;

    }
    else
    {
        test.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

But now working as I want to just hide/show that basic `<tr runat="server" id="test">` and not add additional trs

EDIT : Just dont understand why instead of hiding/showing the tr its leaving the existing one as is. And instead hiding/showing a complete different one.

Comment: Why trigger a postback for this? The row can easily be hidden with client-side script without the need to hit the server again. If the postback does other things, fine, but if all you're doing is updating the ui why add the overhead of a trip to the server?

Comment: Because I want to turn off the validation aswell.

Comment: Wow, this is seriously weird.   Even if you remove the functionality in the event handler, the extra row gets added.  What's even weirder, is every time the update panel gets called, it adds a comma to the text box.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea whats going on, I thought this would be simple but it is a nightmare. I was also maybe trying to add a cssClass to a tr or div and see if I can hide it that way but how on earth you supposed to do that via code behind as I cant assign its a read only value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think tables are messing you up.

Basically the markup you've created is:

```
<table>
    <div id="theUpdatePanel">
        <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

and that `<div>` is not valid.  You should try to put the content into a `<div>` instead.  I've also made the second update panel conditional and triggers off of the Radio button.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="test">
            Director First Name:
            <asp:TextBox ID="DirectorfirstNametxt" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="None" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Director First Name is required." ControlToValidate="DirectorfirstNametxt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="isDirector" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Edit 1:
By the HTML specification, `<table>` elements cannot directly contain `<div>` elements.  The UpdatePanel renders as a `<div>`, thereby generating invalid markup.

The following are both valid, however:

```
<div id="theUpdatePanel">
    <table>
        <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

or:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>    <div id="theUpdatePanel1">foo</div>    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    <div id="theUpdatePanel2">bar</div>    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Edit 2 - What about this?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
<tr class="choose">
    <td>
        Are you a director or company secretary of this nonprofit?
    </td>
    <td>

                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="isDirector" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"
                    AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="isDirector_CheckedChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" Selected></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="isDirectorCompleted" Display="None" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Are you company director/secretary must be selected." ControlToValidate="isDirector"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="test">
            <td class="title">
                Director First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DirectorfirstNametxt" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="None" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Director First Name is required." ControlToValidate="DirectorfirstNametxt"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I need to keep the table formatting, also not to sure what you meant by and that <div> is not valid. You should try to put the content into a <div>. ANyway I tried you code but adding my table mark up back in but same again just creating a second version of the textbox outside my current table

Comment: If you need to keeep the table structure, you need to find a better place for the UpdatePanel.  Either outside of the `<table>` or inside of the `<td>`.

Comment: Hey Greg, I just cant see how the above can work for me I cant place the Update panel with the <td> because then if I hide it the row will still display even if blank. ANd I cant see how I can play it around the table either cuz I need to hide only certain elements in the table

Comment: You'd have to hide the contents of each individual <td>, not the row itself.  The only other alternative is to wrap a larger section of the page in the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Ok Greg I see what your saying, Im going to try out some of the stuff you have mentioned and come back to you. You have been great help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the HtmlControl your trying to modify

```
protected HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow test;

private void isDirector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(isDirector.SelectedValue == "True")
    {
        test.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        test.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error CS0102: The type 'register' already contains a definition for 'test'

Comment: My mistake, you don't need to declare it in the codebehind. But I tried your code in a test site, and it worked for me. The panel should be hid on pageload probably, but it functioned right. So something else in your code is messing it up. Does it inject an entire new row with the "Director First Name: [textbox]" in it?

Comment: Yeah where I toggle with the radio box it toggles on/off an entire now row outside my tabe. And leaves the one I want to change unaffected

Comment: Thats odd, sounds like some sort of compatibility issue. You might want to try Greg's answer, div's are more likely to behave correctly. I wanted to suggest it as well, but I prefer not second guessing people's reasons for choosing a method.

Comment: Yeah I replied to Greg I need to keep table structure, but I dunno ajax does not want to play ball for some reason

Answer (score 1):

The most concrete way to fix your problem would be to add your controls dynamically from the code behind.

That can be kind of a pain if it isnt necessary, so using the ASP:Table, ASP:TableRow etc instead of the HTML controls will also likely fix your problem.

Example:

```
    <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="test">
            <asp:TableCell runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="DirectorfirstNametxt" runat="server" MaxLength="100" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" Display="None" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Director First Name is required." ControlToValidate="DirectorfirstNametxt"/>
            </asp:TableCell>  
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

Then follow with your *test.Visible = false* logic.

Because they were built for it, the ASP controls will generally respond better to manipulations from the code behind. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this combination for showing/hiding rows server-side using CSS classes. You must change the "class" attribute on the control and be explicit about the setting.

CSS:

```
tr.HideRows > td
{
  display:none; 
}

tr.ShowRows > td
{
  display:inline;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="test" runat="server" class="HideRows">
  <td>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Source:

```
protected void isDirector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{         
   if(isDirector.SelectedValue == "True")         
   {             
      this.Test.Attributes("class") = "ShowRows";              
   }         
   else         
   {             
      this.Test.Attributes("class") = "HideRows";            
   }     
}
```